# Ruby regular expression - something between two phrases

Tags: ruby, regex

I have regexp like this:

```
  hours_and_address_reg = /(?<=<span class="infoTitle">godziny otwarcia: <\/span>).*?(?=<div id="singleOutpostIcons">)/
```

So I want to get all the text between

```
<span class="infoTitle">godziny otwarcia: <\/span>
```

and `<div id="singleOutpostIcons">`

And sample document (I keep it in String variable) like this:

```
<span class="infoTitle">godziny otwarcia: </span>
        pn-pt: <span class="openHours">9.00-17.00</span><br/> 
                so: <span class="openHours">zamkni&#x119;te</span><br/> 
                nd: <span class="openHours">zamkni&#x119;te</span><br/> 

        <span class="infoTitle">obs&#x142;uga kasowa: </span>
        pn-pt: <span class="openHours">  09:00-17:00</span><br/> 
                so: <span class="openHours"> -</span><br/> 
                nd: <span class="openHours"> -</span><br/> 


    <hr class="break-line">

    <div id="singleOutpostIcons">
```

What is the problem?
This regex is correct, I checked it on http://rubular.com/

But the line

```
  hours_and_address = hours_and_address_reg.match(address_and_hours_box).to_s
  puts hours_and_address
```

puts nothing.

Maybe the problem are break lines?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want as results plz ?

Comment: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Comment: use `s` or `DOTALL` flag

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.
The solution for Ruby:

```
  hours_and_address_reg = Regexp.new('(?<=<span class="infoTitle">godziny otwarcia: <\/span>).*?(?=<div id="singleOutpostIcons">)', Regexp::MULTILINE)
```